# C# generated excel file - issue with special chars

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, excel

Firstly, here is my code:

```
DataTable usersReport = reportsService.GenerateUsersReport();

var grid = new GridView();
grid.DataSource = usersReport;
grid.DataBind();

Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=UsersReport.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

Response.Charset = "";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

grid.RenderControl(htw);

Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

As you can see, I just generate in simply way report about users. When I open this file in excel, there is a problem with special chars, like `ś,ż,ź,ó,ę,ą` etc.

Instead of `Imię` I can see `ImiÄ™`.
The same issue with `GyÅ¼yÅ„ski`

How can I resolve it?

EDIT:

Add that lines:

```
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
```

Now `Imię` looks like `Imiê`. In conclusion - still nothing

Comment: Probably a codepage/encoding issue - do you know the input codepage/format?

Comment: Maybe add the same encoding to the header of your response as the one the actual page has.

Comment: `System.Text.Encoding.Default` means `UTF8Encoding`. You probably want to apply `Response.Charset = "UTF-8";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little investigation I discover a solution. Important is `<meta>` tag for source HTML.

so that line:

```
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
```

should looks like:

```
Response.Output.Write("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8'>" + sw.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? It could be that the header of the excel file missing the Byte Order Mark(BOM) sequence, try using [GetPreamble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getpreamble%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=UsersReport.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

grid.RenderControl(htw);

Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will Wrk for Speical char and remove null from Excel to 
**From datatable we are creating Excel which Write Special charater also**

***The main trick is making it UTF-32 and applying BinaryWrite***

```
    public void DataTableToExcel(DataTable dt)
    {
        string attachment = "attachment; filename=download.xls";
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32;
    Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetPreamble());
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";

        string tab = "";
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns) // table col
        {
            Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName);
            tab = "\t";
        }
        Response.Write("\n");

        int i;
        string content = "";
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) // Data Row by row
        {
            tab = "";
            for (i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                content = dr[i].ToString();
                content = content.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, " ");
                Response.Write(tab + content);
                tab = "\t";
            }
            Response.Write("\n");
        }
        Response.End();
    }
```